# Convert Java three part for loop to Swift

Tags: swift

I'm having a great deal of difficulty translating the following for loop into Swft

```
for (int i = 0; i * denomAmount <= amount; i++ {
}
```

my attempt is

```
for i in stride(from: 0, to: amount, by: denom){
}
```

but obviously it amount is not the maximum value of i. So what is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Is `demonAmount` or `amount` being updated inside the loop? Use a `while` loop.

Comment: check this [LINK](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html)

Comment: No, neither variable are altered within the loop

Comment: Then you can use `for i in 0...amount/denom`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely either `demonAmount` or `amount` is being updated inside the loop. So I would use a `while` loop:

```
var i = 0
while i * demonAmount <= amount {
    // the loop code
    i += 1
}
```